# python couchdb data collection stops

Tags: python, database, couchdb

I am using couchdb to store twitter data. I found that couchdb stops updating its data base though I keep getting the twitter data. I basically store the dictionary that contains twitter data by using the python couchdb save method, db.save(twitter_dic) where db is the database instance. I find that some times I get 3GB of data and couchdb stops storing, sometimes it stops storing even when it reaches 0.6GB. I don't know what is the reason. If some one have come across similar situation please help me out. If this problem cannot be solved I would look forward to use some other key-value data base where python is used as wrapper to store the values (Very similar to CouchDB) where I can do map reduce etc, can some one provide me such a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to re install couchdb and I am marking this question accepted.